# If I use scope_identity() ; is it possible that it can return the value of a wrong row if several users are using the application at the same time

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, scope-identity

I am novice in programming world, so please forgive my ignorance.

I want to retrieve the primary key value of a row I just inserted. The primary key values are automatically generated. I want to insert that primary key value into another table as a foreign key.

This is the code to insert data in 1st table

```
Core.DB.DoQuery("insert into survey(id, title, detail, employerid, userid) values(@id, @title, @detail, @eid, @uid);", 
                Core.DB.SIP("title", surveyTitle.Text), 
                Core.DB.SIP("detail", surveyDetail.Text), 
                Core.DB.SIP("eid", LocalHelper.UserEmployerID()), 
                Core.DB.SIP("uid", LocalHelper.UserID()), 
                Core.DB.SIP("id", survey))
```

where `DoQuery` is

```
Shared Sub DoQuery(ByVal commandText As String, ByVal ParamArray params As SqlParameter())
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing

        Try
            conn = GetOpenSqlConnection()
            DoQuery(conn, commandText, params)
        Finally
            If conn IsNot Nothing Then conn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

In the above code the id which is the primary key is automatically generated. I want to retrieve that value to insert it as `surveyid` into 2nd table.

```
Core.DB.DoQuery("insert into surveyquestioncategory(title, detail, surveyid) values(@title, @detail, @sid)", 
                Core.DB.SIP("title", categoryTitle.Text), 
                Core.DB.SIP("detail", categoryDetail.Text), 
                Core.DB.SIP("sid", Survey.ID))
```

And by retrieving the id of 2nd table wan to insert the value on 3rd table.

To retrieve the id value of recently inserted row we can use

```
Core.DB.DoQuery("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS MostRecentID")
```

As this is an web application and several users are using the application at the same time is it possible that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` can return value of wrong row. If so how can I avoid that?

Please forgive my ignorance about programming.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks 
Bashabi

Comment: Use `OUTPUT inserted.ID` - this will return right value always. [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: While OUTPUT is a viable (and usually preferred) methodology there is nothing wrong with SCOPE_IDENTITY. You won't get values from another user because they will have a different connection to the database and as such the insert would not be in the same scope.

Comment: scope_identity() returns the last identity value generated (or inserted) in the current scope. in your situation, I'm not sure it's in the same scope as the insert row. Fabio's answer should is a good solution, though if you do both the insert and select scope_identity in the same scope it should be equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `OUTPUT` statement you can do it in one query or create procedure for this

```sql
INSERT INTO survey (id, title, detail, employerid, userid) 
OUTPUT @title, @detail, inserted.ID INTO surveyquestioncategory (title, detail, surveyid)
VALUES (@id, @title, @detail, @eid, @uid);
```

From MSDN [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)